# Can Windows XP use net send command to send a message to a later version of windows?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

The net send command can only be used in Windows XP or earliar versions. But can a Windows XP computer send a message to a later version of windows using the net send command?

Comment: If the service that enables the `net send` functionality is available and running on later versions of Windows, I think it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Windows Messenger service required for NET SEND functionality does not exist on Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8. The service is disabled by default on Windows XP SP2 and SP3.

You'll need to use the **MSG** command instead.